# HDFS ingestion rate frequently drops drastically from all Flume agents. How to investigate/rectify?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I have a good sized Hadoop cluster, with multiple Flume agents (1 agent per machine, not part of the cluster) writing to using HDFSSink. Almost 95% of the time, the Sink batch completion rate is in line with source event rate, thus showing minimal channel size utilization. This is the ideal scenario.

But once in a while, all the agent-sinks start suffering from very low batch completion rate, and channel backs up, which I think is a result of HDFS ingestion rate going down. It does recover automatically after few hours.

Any ideas/pointers as to how to investigate/rectify this scenario?

Comment: We found that the channels back up when one or more hadoop datanodes are getting rebooted (for upgrade or any activity that needs restart). The longer the reboot time, longer the period it takes to normalize the channel fill percent. I am still looking at why all the agents suffer even if one datanode gets recycled.